# How to use value from field as $table?

Tags: php, hidden

I have the table name in the form as a hidden field, i have to do it this way for some reason but it's not working when i do the following:

```
 // This is being processed from the previous page in a form
 $table = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['just_field']);

//Here i am using the $table value to use in place of a table name
$sql = "select `Field` from `$table` where `another_field` = '$id' 
and `another_another_field` = '$something'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    $somefield = $row['field'];
  }
 mysql_free_result($query);
```

How can i make it work so the `$table` is being read by the command...

Comment: print the contents of the `$sql` variable before  you run your query. Is it well formed?

Comment: Remove the quotes around the `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Comment: yes that was a typo but still doesn't solve problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to include the connection string

```
$sql = "select `Field` from `$table` where `another_field` = '$id' 
and `another_another_field` = '$something'";
$query = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    $somefield = $row['field'];
  }
 mysql_free_result($query);
```

if you are not using any framework

Answer (score 2):

No need for quotes around the table assignment.

```
$table = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['just_field']);
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo though that is not the problem

Comment: @SamKhan: Can you post the error you are getting so we can better help you?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is case-sensitivity.

In your query:

```
select `Field` from `$table`....
        ^ Capital F
```

And the later

```
$somefield = $row['field'];
                   ^ lower case f
```

An example

```
php > $cxn = mysql_connect( 'localhost', '****', '****' );
php > mysql_select_db( 'test' );
php > $res = mysql_query( 'select * from genres' );
php > $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $res );
php > print_r( $row );
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => Pop //notice the field name is lower case
)
php > echo $row['name']; //this works
Pop // <- see
php > echo $row['Name']; //this doesn't
php > // <- look, nothing
```

Comment: I doubt this one. When returning a column name for results, case sensitivity does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you

```
$sql = "select `Field` from ".$table." where `another_field` = '$id' 
and `another_another_field` = '$something'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try printing the contents of `$table` before sending it through `mysql_real_escape_string()` to make sure it contains the value you think it does.